# A real system of bilinear equations with $2n$ unknown and equations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization, matrix-equations, multilinear-algebra

I have the following system of $2n$ bilinear equations, for a square invertible matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}_{n \times n}$, and $2n$ unknowns organized in vectors $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$: 
$$
diag(y) A x = {\mathbf 1}_n
$$
$$
diag(x) A^T y = {\mathbf 1}_n
$$
where $diag(x)$ denotes a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements $x$, and ${\mathbf 1}_n$ is a vector of ones of length $n$.

1. What can be said about the solution of this system? for example, when is there a (unique?) solution?
   While in general solving bilinear equations is hard, 
   this system has a specialized simple symmetric structure that can be used.
2. We can easily implement an iterative algorithm with iterations: 
   $$
   x^{(t+1)} = (diag(y^{(t)})A)^{-1} {\mathbf 1}_n
   $$
   $$
   y^{(t+1)} = (diag(x^{(t)})A^T)^{-1} {\mathbf 1}_n.
   $$

What can be said about the convergence of this algorithm? is there a better approach? any hope for a closed-form solution?